# Having issues with mousemove and images in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make the other images also follow the mouse? Not all at the same time, but when I click on the selected image.

How can I calculate the distance where the mouse moved when I click on the image?

See link below.

HTML:

```
<div id="squarelocation"></div>
<div class="square 1">1</div>
<div class="square 2">2</div>
<div class="square 3">3</div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var i = true;
     $(document).on('click', function () {
         $(this)[i ? 'on' : 'off']('mousemove', follow);
         i = !i;
     });

     function follow(e) {
         var xPos = e.pageX;
         var yPos = e.pageY;

         $("#squarelocation").html("The square is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos + "pixels");
         $(".2").offset({
             left: e.pageX,
             top: e.pageY
         });

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to bind a click event to the square class like this:

```
 var clickedImage;
 $('.square').click(function (e){
     initialX = e.pageX;
     initialY = e.pageY;
     clickedImage = this;
 });
```

and assign the context to a variable, so that you can refer to it whenever you needed. And then in your code, refer to that context instead of the hardcoded '.2':

```
 $(clickedImage).offset({
     left: e.pageX,
     top: e.pageY
 });
```

This way, the image clicked will be referred to, instead of just '2' following the mouse all the time.

Same for calculating the distance between the clicked origin and the current position, you can save the original spot on clicking the image:

```
 var initialX;
 var initialY;
 $('.square').click(function (e){
     initialX = e.pageX;
     initialY = e.pageY;
     clickedImage = this;
 });
```

and do the calculation in the 'follow' function, of course how the calculation should be is up to you, but here is an example:

```
 var distanceX = xPos - initialX;
 var distanceY = yPos - initialY;
 $("#squarelocation").html("The square is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos + "pixels");
 $('#squaredistance').html("Distance from origin: " + distanceX + ", " + distanceY);
```

Hope this help. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FW9jV/1/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am going to try it out and review in detail all your comments. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an 'active' class for the active square. I added an example.
The active square will always be moving until you click to deactivate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fG6kr/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = true;
    $('.square').on('click', function () {
        if( $(this).hasClass("active"))
        {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(document).off('mousemove');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(document).on('mousemove', follow);
        }
    });

    function follow(e) {
        var xPos = e.pageX;
        var yPos = e.pageY;

        $("#squarelocation").html("The square is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos + "pixels");
        $('.active').offset({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you. I am playing around with this too for a bit.

Comment: Is the class "active" defined in the CSS? I am not sure about that part. Thanks

Comment: You don't use the "active" class as a style. You use it as a flag for jQuery to determine which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsbin.com/OBEgAtIt/1/edit)

```
$(function() {

  $('.square').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('sel');
  });

  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $(".sel").offset({left: e.pageX+10, top: e.pageY+10});
  });

});
```